# Redux-form ownProperties is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form, url-parameters

I have a redux-form that I'm connecting to the state as follows:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',
  validate // validation function given to redux-form
})(MyForm));
```

I now would like to get a slug value which is a react-router param (after navigating to the page like this:
 *browserHistory.push(`/mypage/${slug}`)* ). However ownProps is empty:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    console.dir(ownProps); // ISSUE:  this is empty 

    const someField = selector(state, 'someField');
    ...
};
```

I tried different ways of connected to redux-form, but haven't been successful. Would really appreciate any hints on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood your problem here. You need to connect the redux form in order to get values using selector. Please see example code below. Hope it will help you.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'
import validate from './validate'
import example from './components/example'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function myForm ({
  someProp,
  exampleClick
}) {
  function handleSubmit (e) {
  }
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field
      name='name'
      component={example}
      submitBtnClicked={exampleClick} />
  </form>
}

let thisForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
  validate
})(myForm)

const selector = formValueSelector('myForm')

thisForm = connect(
  state => {
    const someField = selector(state, 'someField')
    return ({someField})
  }
)(thisForm)

export default thisForm
```

Comment: Hi Umesh, thank you for your reply. I already have an implementation very similar to what you posted here. My issue is not getting it to work with selector. My issue is that I need to use ownProps parameter as an argument to mapStateToProps to extract react router params from the url. It seems like ownProps are always undefined if I add it. I have this working for a component that doesn't use redux-form, so my guess is either I'm not using it correctly with redux-form, or redux-form doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding react-router's *withRouter* around my connected component:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',
  validate // validation function given to redux-form
})(MyForm)));
```